# Is it correct to say, "Any which one of you can attend"?

Tags: sentence

If there is a choice given for two persons to attend a meeting which of the given sentences would be right.

> Any which one of you can attend.

OR

> Any one of you can attend.

Is one better than the other or are they both equally correct?

Comment: The first is ungrammatical. The second is grammatical. But it would also be correct to say - "Any one of which of you can attend". But the last would only follow a specific reference to the two people concerned. e.g. "They are providing one ticket per couple, any one of which can attend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two persons neither is better, and both are not optimal English grammar.

Better:

> Either of you can attend.

**either**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/either)  (see extensive note on either usage at link]

> the one or the other

Comment: which is better either of you can attend  or either one of you can attend

Comment: either of you can attend

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lbf,"Either of you can attend." for the exact reason that was given.

I did want to point out though, if this was your Boss speaking, please think it over before you correct her/him. Some people do not like being corrected and many of them seem to be the Boss !